# In Keil uVision 5, how can I keep the text editor line current while stepping through the debugger?

Tags: debugging, ide, arm, keil

I'm using the education/evaluation version of uVision 5. When debugging my project, the disassembly window marks the next statement that will be executed with a yellow arrow in the margin.

The margin in the text editor for each line will turn green when that line of code has been reached. This would seem to imply that the text editor knows what line of code is currently being executed.

However, the text editor doesn't update unless it loses and regains focus, making it very hard to track what line of code I'm on when debugging. I have to hit F11, then click on the scroll bar in the text editor to see the next line turn green to be able track where I'm at.

I know that there is some way to keep the text editor current with the currently executing code, as there have been a couple of projects I've looked at on a fellow student's computer where the editor was updated with each press of F11 (next statement). However, neither he nor I know how this feature was enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Just close the disassembly window, start debugging with `F10,F11`!!

[image]